# Why is an error reported when the module exceeds 1.0e+18

Tags: python, decimal

Why is an error reported when the module exceeds 1.0e+18?

```py
from decimal import Decimal

M = 1.0e+18

print(M)

M = float(Decimal(M).quantize(Decimal("1E-10"),rounding="ROUND_HALF_UP"))

print(M)
```

Error:

```
InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

Comment: but, if the value is less than or equal to 1.0e+17, it can be passed

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other operations, if the length of the coefficient after the quantize operation would be greater than precision, then an InvalidOperation is signaled. This guarantees that, unless there is an error condition, the quantized exponent is always equal to that of the right-hand operand.

Also unlike other operations, quantize never signals Underflow, even if the result is subnormal and inexact.

If the exponent of the second operand is larger than that of the first, then rounding may be necessary. In this case, the rounding mode is determined by the rounding argument if given, else by the given context argument; if neither argument is given, the rounding mode of the current thread's context is used.